# how to create an extra infinite loop in an gtk/python program?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

New at this, I know that the program is supposed to enter an infinite loop when you call gtk.main. The loop in gtk.main will break when self.quit is called.

But I need another loop active that would check a log file for changes, and keep updating the changes, into a gtk.Textbuffer, to be shown in a gtk.Textbox. So where can i add this loop in the following code.

```
class MessageBox:

    def __init__(self):
        builder = gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file("mbx.glade")
        self.window = builder.get_object("window")
        dic = { "on_buttonSend_clicked" : self.sendmsg,
                "on_entry_activate" : self.sendmsg,
                "on_buttonWhois_clicked" : self.sendwhois,
                "on_buttonIdleTime_clicked" : self.sendidletime,
                "on_window_destroy" : self.exitfunc}
        builder.connect_signals(dic)
        self.entry = builder.get_object("entry")
        self.display = builder.get_object("display")
        self.displaybuff=self.display.get_buffer()

    def exitfunc(self, widget):


    def sendmsg(self, widget):


    def sendwhois (self, widget):


    def sendidletime (self, widget):


if __name__ == "__main__":

    msgbox = MessageBox()
    msgbox.window.show()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: @soulcheck: thanks for that edit, i was wondering how to go about that.

Comment: SO requires 4 spaces indentation on all your code and 4 spaces indents in general. it irritates me alot but suppose that's how it has to be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only exists one mainloop in `gtk` at the same time, that is, `gtk.main` enters into a new level and `gtk.main_quit` exists from that level.

Usually, what you'd need to do is is a create worker thread that keeps working in parallel and updates the widgets when it gets new information. However, according to the problem you describe, I believe you just need to monitor a file for changes with `gio` as follows:

```
monitor = gio.File(filename).monitor()
monitor.connect('changed', file_changed_cb)
```

Whenever the file changes a signal will be emitted and the `file_changed_cb` callback method will be executed. There you can update the widgets to match the new information from the file that is being monitored. However, note that if your callback method takes too long to complete, your application might look unresponive, then you have to go for the thread strategy.

Comment: I wonder about how create worker thread that keeps working in parallel and updates the widgets when it gets new information, is there any implementation example about that?